# Setting a web serer behind a DI-524 router?

Tags: configuration, router

I'm trying to setup a web server behind a DI-524 router, but I'm not being able to make connection from the external network.

I do have a private VPN configured on the same server and it works correctly.

Does anyone has a tip on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the easy guide to port forwarding, even model specific!

http://www.portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Dlink/DI-524/default.htm

Comment: This is driving me crazy... If I connect my computer straight to the ISP everything works... When connecting through the router... nada, niente, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have to open the incoming ports on 80?

Answer (score 0):

Setup port forwarding to your web server.  This is assuming your ISP will allow incoming port 80 traffic.